# Jquery Autocomplete not working on different Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a problem with Jquery Autocomplete.
My code work perfectly but when I change the Data Source, it is not working.

Here is my code and work perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Seach Autocomplete</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="field_id">ID</label>
    <input id="field_id" type="text" style="width: 200px;">
    <label for="field">Search</label>
    <input id="field" type="text" style="width: 200px;">
</body>
</html>
<script>
    $(function() {

        var data = [
            {
                "id": "17",
                "value": "Albania",
                "label": "Albania"
            },
            {
                "id": "18",
                "value": "Algeria",
                "label": "Algeria"
            },
            {
                "id": "20",
                "value": "American Samoa",
                "label": "American Samoa"
            }

        ];

        $("#field").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("#field_id").val(ui.item.id);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**But if I change the data to this below is not working and the result not show up. Here is the data and not working:**

```
{
   "id": 298,
   "city_name": "Jakarta Timur",
   "province_name": "DKI Jakarta"
},
{
   "id": 299,
   "city_name": "Kabupaten Tangerang",
   "province_name": "Banten"
},
{
   "id": 230,
   "city_name": "Jakarta Timur",
   "province_name": "DKI Jakarta"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) it's not working because should be an array of objects with label and value properties: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`. You can use the following code to fix your problem:

```
   $(function() {

        var data = [
            {
                "id": 298,
                "city_name": "Jakarta Timur",
                "province_name": "DKI Jakarta"
            }
        ];
        
        data.forEach(function(obj) {
            let keys = Object.keys(obj);
            obj.label = obj[keys[1]];
            obj.value = obj[keys[2]];
            delete obj[keys[1]];
            delete obj[keys[2]];
            
        });
        

        $("#field").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("#field_id").val(ui.item.id);
            }
        });
   });
```